# SSKeychain not retain data

Tags: ios, sskeychain

I am using `SSKeychain` for storing UUID of device. However, sometimes `SSKeychain` not retains UUID, so my app has to recreate new UUID. Can someone tell me some reasons why `SSKeychain` not retains data.

Thanks in advance!

sorry for my english :)

Comment: Did you use this method in appdelegates for create UUID

Comment: let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if userDefaults.objectForKey("ApplicationIdentifier") == nil {
            let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
            userDefaults.setObject(UUID, forKey: "ApplicationIdentifier")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }

Comment: and one more suggestion create a new SSkeychain Certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But I wonder that, if we store UUID in NSUserDefaults, when user delete app, UUID will be also remove. so, we have to recreate a new UUID.

I have been using SSKeychain open source library for storing UUID. I generated a unique device string and used the keychain to store. Through UUID, I can manage the number of devices that are using at a care center. Recently, the real number of devices is different with the number that I found in DB. So, I think that the UUID of some devices can not be get from SSKeychain and recreate new UUID.

Comment: in iPhone some time thats problem face in some devices so in that case you can do as so in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in your appdelegates for Objective C**

```
NSString *uniqueId = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"YOUR_PROJECT_IDENTIFIER" account:@"unique_id"];

if ([uniqueId length]==0)
{
      uniqueId = [AppDelegate uuid];
      [SSKeychain setPassword:uniqueId forService:@"Store credentials in Keychain Identifier" account:@"unique_id"];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:uniqueId forKey:@"iPhoneUniqueID"];
NSLog(@"Device_ID:%@",uniqueId);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! **br**
I wanna confirm , SSKeychain will be not retain data when:**br**
1. Changing team developer in my project.**br**
2. Download new provisioning profile. 
3. Upgrade iOS or anything else?

Comment: Download New Provisioning profile use that profile for SSKeychain . Hope your problem will be solve

Comment: @user6407153 i have face same problem that you face and i made some changes that i tell you and my problem will be solve and i update my UUID method with above one. if your problem solve with my solution then approve my answer and give me up vote. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your support!
This is my first time I face this problem, my knowledge about SSKeychain is   so bad. So, could you explain in detail for me how to put your code above in the project. 
<pre> [SSKeychain setPassword:uniqueId forService:@"Store credentials in Keychain Identifier" account:@"unique_id"];
<code>
This string @"Store credentials in Keychain Identifier"  mean what?
one more, thanks so much!

Comment: When you use this code inside  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  }  that run that code and access your keychain from your project and your keychain password for particular development account .and i also new in SSKeychain so i dont help you more for this point . i am sorry about this .

Comment: Thanks for your support! :)

Comment: Welcome @pbcuong is your problem solve then give up vote for my answer . Thank you.