# Apple Notification Device Token change

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm facing an issue after updating my app. I'm getting a device token in this format
`C43461D5-E9CB-4C10-81F8-020327A07A62`
and the notifications aren't working.

Before, I had a notification in this format:
`2add70865401171c7ca1d3b3957b719eaf721fef8f8d7a52bc91ef8a872cc004`

I did allow notifications for the app and I've not changed anything in the backend. Can anyone guide me why it's not working?

Code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Getting the device token:

```
NSString *deviceTokenID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DEVICE_TOKEN_PUSH_NOTI];
if ([deviceTokenID isEqualToString:@""] || deviceTokenID == nil) {
    NSString *tempApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [dics setObject:tempApplicationUUID forKey:@"cust_device_id"];
} else {
    [dics setObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DEVICE_TOKEN_PUSH_NOTI] forKey:@"cust_device_id"];
}
```

I got the below error:

> Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for
>   application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid
>   'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}, no valid
>   'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: can you show ur code of didfinishlaunch

Comment: also show your code of getting device token.

Comment: "if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }"

Comment: Show your code of getting device token and show it in your code please not in comment.

Comment: how you take device token?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990629/sskeychain-not-retain-data/39992564#39992564 refer my answer

Comment: I have updated the question please check

Comment: check your provisional profile  and check the server side which ssl certificate they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on .xcodeproj -> Capabilities -> Enable Push Notification

[image]

Comment: @Jack this is just used for background modes of push notifications. It has nothing to do with why push notif doesn't come. In short this is **NOT** used to **Enable** push notif. This is just used to handle notifications in background mode

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari this ans is related to error get. So i just give ans for that error "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application".

Answer (score 3):

[image]

plz go to

Click on .xcodeproj -> Capabilities -> Enable Push Notification

hope it's work

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *tempApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

The UUIDString is the Unique device ID but for the Apple Push Notification you required the device token get back from APNS so for that Use the below method you get 64 digit deviceToken and get notification.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken


{
    NSString *devToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


    NSString *str = [NSString
                     stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",devToken];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:devToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

}
```

Comment: Please don't use `[NSData description]`! It's not a good way to stringify push tokens because the description can change any time.

Comment: Well, it seems it has changed in iOS 13.