# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and iOS13 where is token?

Tags: push-notification, ios13

Since iOS 13 device token given by didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is no more easy to catch as NSString what's happened ? of course push didn't works !

Comment: Can you share some code that demonstrates your problem? How are you trying to get the token string?

Comment: token was return before iOS13 by [deviceToken description] this is a wrong method now solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839723/does-ios-13-has-new-way-of-getting-device-notification-token