# iOS 10.3 beta 3 doesn't persist data of KeychainItem

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, keychain, ios10.3

I have observed behavior of app in iOS 10.2.1 device and iOS 10.3 beta 3 device for https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Keychain data is being deleted in iOS 10.3 beta 3.
That was still found in earlier versions.

Do we have any alternative to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that 10.3 has been officially released, it's been confirmed by several parties, including in this [Apple's developers forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/210531#210531), that this issue is **not** present in the final release.

Keychain data is not being deleted upon app's uninstall.

Answer (score 7):

**Originally** *(Since iOS 10.3 beta 1 to 5?)* the keychain **WAS NOT** persisted.

> *Apple staff:*
>
> This is an intentional change in iOS 10.3 to protect user privacy. Information that can identify a user should not be left on the device after the app that created it has been removed.

---

#### But since *iOS 10.3 beta 6*, the keychain IS persisted again.

Nobody gives you any reassurances it will work that way in the future.

While it is fine to use it the way we do, **I strongly encourage you to write your app so that it acts reasonably if this behaviour change**.

Comment: Yes, from Apple developer forum seems it was just enabled for the beta versions, but finally they cancelled it...

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10.3 beta 2 keychain information will be deleted when an app is deleted. Keychain information used to persist between app uninstall and reinstalls but that was not intended behavior and was a side effect of implementation that people got used to.

You'll probably just have to get used to the new behavior unless they have a top secret keychain replacement in the pipeline. keychain data should still persist since 10.3 beta 2 across app uninstall / reinstall by using an app group that shares said keychain info and having another application in the app group installed; so it doesn't delete the keychain info. Also I would guess it doesn't delete items synchronized with iCloud from iCloud but just deletes the local copy. Just a guess though.

Here is a link to an apple developer forum on the issue:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/210531#210531