# How to Identify application previously installed in iOS Device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any way to **identify** the particular application that has been **installed** previously on the same iOS device or not? **after reinstalling**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) to store some data you need to detect a previous installation. Keychain is a secure storage for sensitive data like passwords or tokens, and data left there after app deleted. So, do not store too much data there.

Also, you can use some wrapper like [this](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift) to simple access.

Comment: This is incorrect as of iOS 10.3 - the keychain will be deleted.

Comment: @sooper Thanks for the info. A found this thread on Apple's developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/210531

Also, I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43063683/2739795
I didn't try by myself but looks like in public release for 10.3 keychain data not removed.

Comment: Actually we can't be sure that if it is deleted... There are chances that it will be deleted, since it wasn't a feature anyways

Comment: Interesting comment. I hadn't heard of this so went researching and found the same link as noted above by @AndrewBogaevskyi. It looks like Apple has rolled back these intended changes because one undesirable side effect was the removal of iCloud keychain items, which may be shared with other devices that may note have uninstalled the app.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi You're right, it looks like it was rolled back for the 10.3 release due to the iCloud keychain bug.  But because of it being in the 10.3 betas I wouldn't count on this behavior in the future.  We'll probably see the change in 10.4 or 11 once Apple works out the bug.